# Ruby - test each array element, get one result

Tags: arrays, ruby, fold

I want a one-liner to return true/false, that tests each element in an array for whether it's an Integer or not. So if any element in the array is not an Integer, it should return false, else true. Here's my try:

```
>> ([2,1,4].map {|x| (x.is_a? Integer)}).reduce {|x, result| x and result}
=> true
>> ([2,"a",4].map {|x| (x.is_a? Integer)}).reduce {|x, result| x and result}
=> false
```

Any other ideas to distill it down further?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
array.all?{ |x| x.is_a? Integer }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ary.all?(&Integer.method(:===))
```

Comment: I really wish Ruby had a better syntax for accessing methods. This is more conceptually pure, but in practice actually longer than writing out the explicit block.

Comment: @Chuck: Yeah. There is an idea floating around which pops up every couple of years to make a better distintion between the `.` (message sending) and `::` (scope resolution) operators. Currently, `.` means message sending and `::` means scope resulotion or message sending. If we remove the "or message sending" part from `::`, we can extend it to allow stuff like `foo::bar` to mean `foo.method(:bar)`. Currently, that doesn't work, since `foo::bar` means the same as `foo.bar`.